# Oracle APEX: Disable a button with dynamic actions

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-apex

I need to disable apply changes button when user click once on that button. i need to do this without changing the Button template. so, is there any way to do this with dynamic actions ?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the Apply button submits the page?  If so then you can have a submit computation or process that sets a hidden item e.g. P1_APPLY_PRESSED to 'Y'.  Then you can create a dynamic action that fires when P1_APPLY_PRESSED = 'Y' that disables the button, specifying its ID value as a DOM object.  You can use the Static ID property of the button to give it a simple ID e.g. "applyButton".